# Default Memberwise Initializers for Structure Types with private(set)

Tags: swift, struct, initialization, structure, private

Why does Swift 4 allow us to modify `private(set)` variables in the "Default Memberwise Initializer"? Is that a bug or a feature? And more important, what is the easiest way to avoid this and keep the same functionality of `private(set)`?

Example Code:

```
import Foundation

struct MyStruct {
    private(set) var counter = 0
}

let myStruct = MyStruct(counter: 5) //Should not be allowed in my opinion
print(myStruct.counter)            //Returns 5
```

Comment: Why do you think this should not be allowed? There is no violation of private access being done here. `private` means only the class code can update the property. The initializer is part of the class. It's allowed to change any private variable.

Comment: Okay. But if I set the var private, the initializer is not allowed to set it.

Comment: If the property is fully private, the implicitly created `init` method is also private. If you add your own non-private initializer, that initializer is still allowed to set the private property.

Answer (score 0):

The rules are different at the moment of initialization than at any other time, because it is necessary to initialize all properties as part of initialization. That is why even a `let` property without a value can be given a value in the initializer; that is the *only* time a `let` constant can be assigned to by other code. This is therefore legal:

```
struct MyStruct {
    let counter : Int
    init(counter:Int) { self.counter = counter } // ok to assign to `let`
}
```

Keep in mind that the supplied memberwise initializer is just an initializer like any other. You could have written it explicitly. Suppose you had written this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    private(set) var counter : Int
    init(counter:Int) { self.counter = counter }
}
let myStruct = MyStruct(counter: 5)
```

You do not deny, I suppose, that *that* makes sense? There is now no default initialization in the `counter` declaration, so the *only* way to give it an initial value would be the initializer. And this would also be *necessary*, since we must initialize all properties as part of object initialization.

Well, your code is not appreciably different. You do provide default initialization, but the memberwise initializer is still an initializer and is permitted to give the property a value.

If your goal was to make it impossible to change the value of `counter` *at all* after its initial value was provided, then it should have been a `let` constant, not a `var` variable.

If your goal was to make it legal to initializer MyStruct with or without an explicit `counter`, then you could have written the same thing this way:

```
struct MyStruct {
    private(set) var counter : Int
    init(counter:Int = 0) { self.counter = counter }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick replay. I understand that I have to "overwrite" the "Default Memberwise Initializer" with my own init. Okay, but does that make sense that the "Default Memberwise Initializer" does not care about private settings?
If I set my counter to private not private(set), it can't be modified with the "Default Memberwise Initializer"

Comment: That is because if any property is pure `private` the memberwise initializer itself becomes private. So it cannot be called by saying `MyStruct(counter: 5)`. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html under "Default Memberwise Initializers for Structure Types". So you're saying you think the same thing _should_ be true if a property is `private(set)` as well?